# Creating Auto suggest box into multiple column in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, autosuggest, c#-6.0, xamarin.uwp

I already implement the Auto Suggestion box in my application but the problem is I want to make the suggestion Flyout into Multiple columns and not the ordinary suggestion list with only one column.

Also, I want to make the suggestion list wider than the Textbox,
    for Example, I set AutoSuggestBox control to 100 (textbox) and I want the suggestion list to set like the width of 300.

I tried Control.ItemTemplate on my Renderer but I don't know how to start and put some object on the Control.ItemTemplate because I saw some implementation on the Native that you can customize.

on UWP XAML they have this implementation to customize the suggestion list

On my UWP Renderer, I have one function like this.

```
        private void UpdateItemsSource()
        {            
            Control.ItemTemplate = new Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate();

            Control.ItemsSource = Element?.ItemsSource;
        }
```

I want something to implement like this because maybe it will be the answer to my problem.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6242794-715f-4aa4-91a4-5d8d675fbf71/uwp-xaml-autosuggestbox-with-button-in-itemtemplate?forum=wpdevelop

```
<AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="EditSuggestionButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE104;"
                    Click="EditSuggestionButton_Click" ClickMode="Press"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>

<AutoSuggestBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</AutoSuggestBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make the suggestion Flyout into Multiple columns and not the ordinary suggestion list with only one column.

You could achieve this target by defining a DataTemplate as its ItemsTemplate.

Please see the following code sample for reference:

```
<AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="200"
            TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged">
        <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Desc}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            sender.ItemsSource = GenerateSuggestionData();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Test> GenerateSuggestionData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Test> tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        tests.Add(new Test() { Name = "Alan", Age = 20, Desc = "T1" });
        tests.Add(new Test() { Name = "Helen", Age = 22, Desc = "T2" });
        tests.Add(new Test() { Name = "James", Age = 18, Desc = "T3" });
        return tests;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

> I want to make the suggestion list wider than the Textbox, for Example, I set AutoSuggestBox control to 100 (textbox) and I want the suggestion list to set like the width of 300.

The popup width is controlled in the AutoSuggestBox's code-behind, you could not change it. You could submit your ideas on [microsoft-ui-xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22feature+request%22) github.

Comment: Thank you for sharing an idea but it seems AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate was not available on the Xamarin.Forms UWP because I try it already

Comment: @parpar How did you implement your AutoSuggestBox control?

Comment: I just follow the tutorials here, All property was bindable property

https://github.com/dotMorten/XamarinFormsControls/tree/master/AutoSuggestBox

Comment: @parpar You need to implement the ItemTemplate by yourself and replace it by the UWP localized DataTemplate on your renderer. See [Xamarin.Forms.Core/ListView.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ListView.cs) and [ListViewRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/ListViewRenderer.cs#L65) for more reference.

Comment: Appreciated @xavier Xie. Can you tell me where can I start on this implementation?

Comment: @parpar As I said, please see [Xamarin.Forms.Core/ListView.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ListView.cs) and [ListViewRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/ListViewRenderer.cs#L65).